# How to construct a DolphinDB SQL statement with a multi-output function?

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions, dolphindb

I want to define a UDF to calculate different metrics for one specific column. Can I use such a multi-output function within a SQL statement? For example:

```
tb=table(1 2 3 as `a, 1 1 2 as `b)
def process(x){
    return mean(x),x+1
}
select process(a) from tb context by b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. But you need to use the `as` keyword to assign the multiple results to separate columns:

```
select process(a) as `x`y from tb context by b
```